# javascript cursor image position

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

i change my cursor background to image file , the cursor in top of image

```
$(".mainDiv").attr("style", "cursor: url(./images/myImage.png) ,auto");
```

How to set the cursor in bottom of image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is :

```
$(".mainDiv").attr("style", "cursor: url(./images/myImage.png)  70 120 ,auto");
```

70 120 , padding the cursor in image . Max left is 70 , Max top is 120.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) instead:

```
$(".mainDiv").css({cursor: 'url(./images/myImage.png) ,auto'});
```

Comment: work , but need to set cursor in bottomRight of myImage , not in topLeft , can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mainDiv").css("cursor", "url('url') ,auto");
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AWNB9/)

Comment: it work , but i need to set the cursor on bottom , in Example the cursor position on topLeft of image , can i set it in bottomRight ?